# Android resource linking failed in binding adapter data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I want to set text using binding adapter.Here is the MyBindingAdapter.kt

```
@BindingAdapter("android:setTitle")
fun setTitle(textView : TextView,text: String){
        textView.text = text
}
```

in activity_table.xml I used setTitle like this

```
  <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:setTitle="Hello word"/>
```

and I getting below error in compile time
[image: and I getting below error at compile time]

Comment: What about to add an `id` to your TexttView?

Comment: Does it matter to add id?

Comment: Yeah. As I know...If you don't set any ID,  you can't bind this view.

Comment: Okay I added ID but still same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change from `@BindingAdapter("android:setTitle")` to `@BindingAdapter("setTitle")` in your MyBindingAdapter.kt.

Also you need to change in xml file from  `android:setTitle="Hello word"` to  `setTitle="Hello word"`

It should work now!

Answer (score 3):

Android studio will not consider `@BindingAdapter("android:setTitle")` while binding it, you need to write only `@BindingAdapter("setTitle")` to execute it perfectly, otherwise it will give that binding error while compile time.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you have to enclose you layout within the `<layout>` tag

```
<layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
..... </layout>
```

and `@BindingAdapter("android:setTitle")`  change as `@BindingAdapter("title")`

it should work.